# Databricks Spark Dataframe - mismatching schemas - controlling the errors

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql, databricks

I have a Spark Dataframe in Databricks that I am using to save the data to an existing table:

```
sparkDF.write.mode("append").saveAsTable("dev.bronze_data_table")
```

As long as the schema between the table and the dataframe match, then everything works great.  However, when the schemas don't match, then I get a mismatch error.  I have very little control over the incoming schema - it could be missing columns, have mistyped column names and have extra columns.

I have over 1 billion incoming rows to process and many more rows coming everyday.  I expect the vast majority of the rows will match the table schema.  I would love to get the rows that don't match the table schema to be saved to a separate table.  I know I can do this with up front processing (looking at column names and comparing them to the known schema), but this is a waste of resources for all the rows that match.  Is there an inventive way to extract the error rows from the Spark dataframe at runtime?

Essentially, I try to write all the rows to the table.  The ones that match the table schema are saved, the ones that don't fail.  Then I can process only the failed rows?

Thanks.

Comment: If you save your data as avro the schema changes will be handled automatically.

Comment: @Jacob - Avro is probably much faster (especially fastavro) at validating the data against the schema than Spark Dataframes so this is a good idea.  But I still have the issue of validating all the good rows too.  I am really hoping to find a way to get rid of all the good rows before I start evaluating the problems.

Comment: Why not consider the avro layer as the raw layer and then build a reject and cleansed later afterward? Since it's incremental data you should be fine with the approach, right?

Comment: What is the source of the dataframe you are trying to write?

Comment: @Chris - The data right now is stored in a databricks table.  It is stored in JSON format in a string column so part of the next stage is converting it from JSON into columns and flattening it out.  From there I want to rationalize the schema and store it in a new databricks table as the bronze data layer.

Comment: @Jacob - I can certainly do an Avro layer.  The problem with Avro no matter how I introduce it is that it is going to process all the data rows.  I really want to try and find a way to try the insert on all rows and then just process the failed ones.  That way I allow the conforming rows to just work and the problematic rows to bubble to the forefront naturally.

Comment: There is a spark dataframe mode called "DROPMALFORMED" which seems to do some of what I want.  Unfortunately, I think it validates the data against a provided schema.  There is an "infer schema" option which might allow me to infer the schema from the table, but I still think it is going to manually validate the schema before doing the insert.  I know with regular spark the dropped rows are logged so you can parse the log to find the rows that were dropped.  I am not sure how databricks handles the dropped rows.

Comment: In the past I've accommodated an evolving schema with an ETL step reading the source data with `inferschema` and writing out as Parquet layer. Downstream then reads with `mergeSchema` option. You could then `dropna` for rows with missing columns and possibly iterate over the columns in a filter dropping rows with values in unexpected columns)?